# If $G\cap A_n = \{id\}$, then $|G| \leq 2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ a subgroup of $S_n$, the symetric group of order $n$. Let $A_n$ the group of even elements of $S_n$ (standard notations).

Prove that if $G\cap A_n = \{id\}$, then $|G| \leq 2$.

Comment: What is $G$? And $n$? And $S_n$? And... everything?

Comment: $G$ is a subgroup of $S_n$. $S_n$ is the symmetric group on $n$ letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Assume that $|G| > 1$. 
Let $x\in G $, $x\neq id$.
Then as $x\notin A_n$, $x$ is odd and $x^2$ is even.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will try to work through this.

Comment: do you see how the conclusion looks like?

Comment: Then $x^n$ is even for all $n \geq2$. So $x^n \notin G$ for $n \geq 2$?

Comment: No! $x^2$ is in $G$, and $x^2$ is even, so $x^2  = id$.

Comment: and acutally, if $x,y$ are two non $id$ elements of $G$, you have that $xy = id$. Then $x=y$ and $G = \{id, x\}$